# CMake - what does this OPTION command do?

Tags: syntax, cmake

I'm getting into CMake and have some trouble with the syntax of it. I was wondering if any of you could tell me what the following command does exactly:

```
OPTION(USE_OPENGL "Use OpenGL" FOUND_OPENGL)
```

As far as I can tell, it will Default OPENGL to ON if it is found. Is that correct?

Comment: Have you tried to look into the documentation? http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/option.html

Comment: The issue wasn't knowing what the command (OPTION) does in general (I know what it does), it's what this particular command does. I'm cleaning up the CMake of a modestly-sized project, and this particular command threw me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command provides an option to the user to change a specific aspect of your build system. The syntax is explained in the documentation:

```
option(<option_variable> "help string describing option"
                   [initial value])
```

In your specific case, it will create an option called USE_OPENGL which should have the default value from the FOUND_OPENGL variable. So the default will probably be the same as the result of an automatic check whether opengl is available. However, the syntax is actually wrong in the example you give. It should be:

```
OPTION(USE_OPENGL "Use OpenGL" ${FOUND_OPENGL})
```

Options are specifically available through the `ccmake` command or the cmake gui. Here, the given documentation string will be available to the user. After the user has decided on the option, you can use the the variable given as the first argument like any other boolean variable in CMake. E.g.:

```
IF(USE_OPENGL)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Will us OpenGL")
ENDIF()
```

Comment: So then it will default to ON if OpenGL is found, OFF if it isn't?

i.e., is it the equivalent of:
if(FOUND_OPENGL)
 set(USE_OPENGL ON CACHE BOOL "USE OPENGL")
else(FOUND_OPENGL)
 set(USE_OPENGL OFF CACHE BOOL "USE OPENGL")
endif(FOUND_OPENGL)

?

Comment: @assignment_operator I am not completely sure about the internal differences between cache variables and options. Logically your example looks equivalent. However, if it is clearly a user option, I would chose the option command